# Can I use window phone application project to develop window phone game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using VS 2013 and I wanna develop game for window phone 8. But I don't have XNA. 
My game is not complex and don't has many animation. 
In my opinion, I think app and game are the same.

I need some advice. Please!

Comment: Have you checked the current performance of your game using the app project?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Of cource you can develop simple game on Windows Phone 8.1, but how hard it would be depends of details of your game. XNA isn't the only one way to create games for windows phone.

Comment: I wanna develop a game like sudoku. If I use window phone application project, can I upload xap file to Store as game ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can develop a game. You do not need XNA. As far as the store is concerned a game is just an app that has a category of 'game'.

If it's a Silverlight app you will upload a .XAP to the store; if it's a WinRT app (Windows Phone 8.1) you will upload an appxpackage.